# Two dimensional ArrayList error

Tags: java

I am here trying to get an element from my two dimensional `ArrayList` but getting `IndexOutOfBoundException` error. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to allocate the space like in a simple Array first? If so, How can I do it in two dimensional array? Below is the code,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array;

    public Test(){
        array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        array.get(0).set(0, "00");
        array.get(0).set(1, "01");
        array.get(0).set(2, "02");
        array.get(1).set(0, "10");
        array.get(1).set(1, "11");
        array.get(1).set(2, "12");
        array.get(2).set(0, "20");
        array.get(2).set(1, "21");
        array.get(2).set(2, "22");
    }

    public String getE(int a, int b){
        return array.get(a).get(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test object = new Test();
        System.out.println(object.getE(0, 0)); // This gives me the error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the `ArrayList`s before you insert into them.  Like this:

```
public Test(){
    array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    array.get(0).add("00");
    array.get(0).add("01");
    array.get(0).add("02");
    array.get(1).add("10");
    array.get(1).add("11");
    array.get(1).add("12");
    array.get(2).add("20");
    array.get(2).add("21");
    array.get(2).add("22");
}
```

Right now, `array` is empty, so calling `array.get(0)` will result in the `IndexOutOfBoundException`.  Once you add an initialized `ArrayList` at index 0, you will no longer get that error.

The constructor `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()` makes an empty `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.  It does not initialize the contents of `array`; you need to do that yourself.

Additionally, using `set(int i , E e)` gives you the same problem if there is not already an element at index i.  You should use `add(E e)` instead.  You can read more about `set()` at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int, E).

Comment: Didn't I do it at the constructor? Aren't I initializing the ArrayList with this line of code `array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`?

Comment: Oh I get it. Do I have to initialize a new `ArrayList` for every row to get two dimensional array list?

Comment: @Zip You are making an **empty** `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` with the constructor.  You need to add initialized `ArrayList<String>`s to `array`.

Comment: I am still getting the error though after adding to three line of codes.

Comment: @Zip see my most recent update.  You are getting errors because of `set()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I finally got this.